# Are functions with guards tail recursive

Tags: haskell, tail-recursion

I was wondering if funtions with guards could be tail recursive. Given this implementation of `elem` for example

```
elem' :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem' x [] = False
elem' x (y:ys)
    | x == y       = True
    | otherwise    = elem' x ys
```

Is this tail recursive? I would say yes, but I am somehow not convinced.

Comment: I think due to laziness, it is rather hard to say whether something is tail recursive. Since we do not really know in advance what will be executed.

Comment: ...this is pretty clearly tail-recursive, right? (I don't see the _modulo cons_ connection here either)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem (slightly off-topic, but...) *should* we care, performance-wise? I was under the impression that what Haskell loses in tail call elimination it makes up for in lazy execution.

Comment: @AdamSmith: well I am not talking about tail call *optimization*. I am only saying that in Haskell it is rather unknown what parts will be evaluated first. Since that depends in what the outer functions are interested. As a result the concept of a "tail call" can be seen as a bit non-sensical.

Comment: The notion of a tail call makes perfect sense in Haskell. When execution enters a function, it is because the WHNF of the result of that function is needed, and it will be computed by the time the function returns. Laziness only says that evaluation is restricted to WHNF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is tail recursive.

One possible definition for what “Tail Recursive” means in the context of Haskell is where calls to “join points” are valid, as these may only appear in tail-recursive positions.
On page 3 of [*Compiling without Continuations*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/compiling-without-continuations/) we find this figure:

[image: Tail contexts]

and we see that the right-hand-side of alternatives in a case statement are tail-call positions. We could also find code corresponding to this in the GHC source.

Together with the [desugaring of guards according the Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-460003.13), which tells us that guards are essentially nested `case`-expressions, we can conclude that your function is tail-recursive.

(Although one should say “`elem'` is tail-recursive as a function of two arguments” – without specifying the arity, the question makes less sense.)

Comment: The join point optimization has certain additional restrictions, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, see “Note [Invariants on join points]” in https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/ghc-8.4.1/src/CoreSyn.html